# How to get correct screen coordinate from UITapGestureRecognizer while VoiceOver is on

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover

I'm currently working on an interactive view that relies heavily on the user's touch location. I have found that there are a few ways to interact with the `UITapGestureRecognizer` while `VoiceOver` is on, but when I tap my point the values given are very wrong. I've looked elsewhere, but my use case is outside of the norm so there is not a lot to tell me what is going on. Has anyone experienced this before?

I am aware that I can change `accessibilityTrait` to `UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction` which will give me the correct screen point when used, but I would like to know what is causing this issue at the very least for the sake of knowledge. To interact with the `UITapGestureRecognizer` I either double tap or do a 3D touch by pressing on hard on the screen. The ladder method doesn't work for the tap gesture but will work for the pan gesture.

This is the only line I use to get my screen points. My map view is a `UIImageView`

```
CGPoint screenPoint = [tapGesture locationInView:map];
```

I'm using a map of a building and I try to tap the same corner or landmark for my testing. I know I can't hit the same exact point every time, but I do use a stylus and I can get pretty close.

Without VoiceOver on I would get the result: (35.500, 154.363)

With VoiceOver on and tapping in generally the same spot, I get : (187.500, 197.682)

The point I am using to test is on the left side of the screen and the result from VoiceOver being on is in the middle of the screen. I believe the y-axis value may have changed because of my tool bar's size, but I have no idea what is throwing off the x-axis value. If more information is needed let me know.

UPDATE: Upon further investigation, it turns out that the `UITapGestureRecognizer` will always return (187.500, 197.682) no matter where I touch in the map view when VoiceOver is on. That point seems to be the middle of the map view. Oddly enough though, the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` will give me the correct (x,y) for my view if I use the 3D touch while VoiceOver is on.

On a side note not relating to the problem at hand, it seems if I use the accessibility trait `UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction` the method `UIAccessibilityConvertFrameToScreenCoordinates` returns a frame that is higher than my view. It works fine if I do not change the trait.

Comment: did you get the correct location without UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction

Comment: @ATNASGDWNGTH I'm sorry but it has been a long time since this question was asked. I believe the project ended up getting scrapped and I don't remember if I ever managed to figure out the problem or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may deal with the reference point used when **VoiceOver** is on.
Verify what your point coordinates are referring to : view or screen coordinates ?

I suggest you take a look at the following elements :

- [accessibilityFrame](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615111-accessibilityframe?language=objc)
- [accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityelement/1649543-accessibilityframeincontainerspa?language=objc)
- [UIAccessibilityConvertFrameToScreenCoordinates](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1615145-uiaccessibilityconvertframetoscr?language=objc)

According to your project, the previous elements may be interesting to get your purposes.

Comment: I think it may be using screen coordinates as opposed to the view coordinates. I will take a look at the elements you've listed and see if that solves the issue. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @XLE_22 do you have example about how to use them?

Comment: @ATNASGDWNGTH I'm not sure but you may find some code snippets regarding these elements at this site: https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/ 

Comment: Thanks @XLE_22. If you take a look the iOS built-in Notes app with VoiceOver enabled, you can draw a stroke which respects your finger position. I wonder how apple does that.